# SBT preload failure

Tags: sbt

I have installed sbt in a docker image.
The installation was fine.

```
# installing sbt
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.3.13
RUN apk add wget \
    && wget -O tmp/sbt.tgz "https://piccolo.link/sbt-1.3.13.tgz" \
    && tar -xvzf tmp/sbt.tgz -C /usr/local \
    && export PATH="/usr/local/sbt/bin:$PATH" \
    && sbt sbtVersion \
    && apk del wget \
    && rm tmp/sbt.tgz
```

When i invoked sbt commands inside my container, the commands are successfully executed.
However, it fetches a bunch of packages from maven repository before starting up.

when i invoke sbt commands through jenkins pipeline, it fails...
Below is the Jenkins pipeline code and failure log:

```
docker.withRegistry(.....) {
               pipelineDock = docker.image(...)
                pipelineDock.pull()
                pipelineDock.inside("--entrypoint=''") {
                    stage('test) {
                        sh "sbt clean"
                    }
}
```

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ sbt clean
copying runtime jar...
[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.3.13  (this may take some time)...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/main_2.12/1.3.13/main_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.13/sbt-1.3.13.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/io_2.12/1.3.4/io_2.12-1.3.4.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.10/scala-library-2.12.10.jar ...
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/usr/local/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.3.13!sbt.jar (210ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/logic_2.12/1.3.13/logic_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logic_2.12;1.3.13!logic_2.12.jar (67ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/actions_2.12/1.3.13/actions_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#io_2.12;1.3.4!io_2.12.jar (318ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/main-settings_2.12/1.3.13/main-settings_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#actions_2.12;1.3.13!actions_2.12.jar (51ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/run_2.12/1.3.13/run_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#run_2.12;1.3.13!run_2.12.jar (37ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/command_2.12/1.3.13/command_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings_2.12;1.3.13!main-settings_2.12.jar (125ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/collections_2.12/1.3.13/collections_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#command_2.12;1.3.13!command_2.12.jar (74ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main_2.12;1.3.13!main_2.12.jar (451ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/scripted-sbt-redux_2.12/1.3.13/scripted-sbt-redux_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/scripted-plugin_2.12/1.3.13/scripted-plugin_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#scripted-sbt-redux_2.12;1.3.13!scripted-sbt-redux_2.12.jar (41ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#scripted-plugin_2.12;1.3.13!scripted-plugin_2.12.jar (35ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-lm-integration_2.12/1.3.13/zinc-lm-integration_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#collections_2.12;1.3.13!collections_2.12.jar (61ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.12/1.3.0/scala-xml_2.12-1.3.0.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/launcher-interface/1.1.4/launcher-interface-1.1.4.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-lm-integration_2.12;1.3.13!zinc-lm-integration_2.12.jar (33ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.1.4!launcher-interface.jar (38ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.2/log4j-core-2.11.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.3.0!scala-xml_2.12.jar(bundle) (73ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-api;2.11.2!log4j-api.jar (52ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.2.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/cb372/scalacache-caffeine_2.12/0.20.0/scalacache-caffeine_2.12-0.20.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.10!scala-library.jar (610ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-slf4j-impl;2.11.2!log4j-slf4j-impl.jar (40ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/get-coursier/lm-coursier-shaded_2.12/2.0.0-RC6-4/lm-coursier-shaded_2.12-2.0.0-RC6-4.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-logging_2.12/1.3.3/util-logging_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.cb372#scalacache-caffeine_2.12;0.20.0!scalacache-caffeine_2.12.jar (40ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.logging.log4j#log4j-core;2.11.2!log4j-core.jar (88ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/librarymanagement-core_2.12/1.3.4/librarymanagement-core_2.12-1.3.4.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/librarymanagement-ivy_2.12/1.3.4/librarymanagement-ivy_2.12-1.3.4.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-logging_2.12;1.3.3!util-logging_2.12.jar (50ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compiler-interface/1.3.5/compiler-interface-1.3.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#librarymanagement-ivy_2.12;1.3.4!librarymanagement-ivy_2.12.jar (56ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#librarymanagement-core_2.12;1.3.4!librarymanagement-core_2.12.jar (79ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;1.3.5!compiler-interface.jar (41ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-compile_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-relation_2.12/1.3.3/util-relation_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12/0.8.3/sjson-new-scalajson_2.12-0.8.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-compile_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-compile_2.12.jar (51ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-position_2.12/1.3.3/util-position_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sjson-new-scalajson_2.12;0.8.3!sjson-new-scalajson_2.12.jar (45ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-relation_2.12;1.3.3!util-relation_2.12.jar (49ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-core_2.12/0.8.3/sjson-new-core_2.12-0.8.3.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/shaded-scalajson_2.12/1.0.0-M4/shaded-scalajson_2.12-1.0.0-M4.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-position_2.12;1.3.3!util-position_2.12.jar (40ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#shaded-scalajson_2.12;1.0.0-M4!shaded-scalajson_2.12.jar (39ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/spire-math/jawn-parser_2.12/0.10.4/jawn-parser_2.12-0.10.4.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.10/scala-reflect-2.12.10.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.spire-math#jawn-parser_2.12;0.10.4!jawn-parser_2.12.jar (40ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sjson-new-core_2.12;0.8.3!sjson-new-core_2.12.jar (81ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/completion_2.12/1.3.13/completion_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/task-system_2.12/1.3.13/task-system_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#completion_2.12;1.3.13!completion_2.12.jar (51ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#task-system_2.12;1.3.13!task-system_2.12.jar (44ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/testing_2.12/1.3.13/testing_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/tasks_2.12/1.3.13/tasks_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tasks_2.12;1.3.13!tasks_2.12.jar (37ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-tracking_2.12/1.3.3/util-tracking_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#testing_2.12;1.3.13!testing_2.12.jar (48ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] io.get-coursier#lm-coursier-shaded_2.12;2.0.0-RC6-4!lm-coursier-shaded_2.12.jar (315ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-classpath_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-classpath_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-apiinfo_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-apiinfo_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-tracking_2.12;1.3.3!util-tracking_2.12.jar (31ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc_2.12/1.3.5/zinc_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-classpath_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-classpath_2.12.jar (39ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc_2.12;1.3.5!zinc_2.12.jar (36ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-apiinfo_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-apiinfo_2.12.jar (54ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-control_2.12/1.3.3/util-control_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.10!scala-reflect.jar (204ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/swoval/file-tree-views/2.1.3/file-tree-views-2.1.3.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.5.0/jna-5.5.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] jline#jline;2.14.6!jline.jar (52ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.5.0/jna-platform-5.5.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-control_2.12;1.3.3!util-control_2.12.jar (57ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-interface/1.3.3/util-interface-1.3.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.swoval#file-tree-views;2.1.3!file-tree-views.jar (74ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lmax/disruptor/3.4.2/disruptor-3.4.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-interface;1.3.3!util-interface.jar (44ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.10/scala-compiler-2.12.10.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] net.java.dev.jna#jna;5.5.0!jna.jar (103ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.7.0/protobuf-java-3.7.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.lmax#disruptor;3.4.2!disruptor.jar (81ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] net.java.dev.jna#jna-platform;5.5.0!jna-platform.jar (136ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-cache_2.12/1.3.3/util-cache_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12/0.8.3/sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12-0.8.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.protobuf#protobuf-java;3.7.0!protobuf-java.jar(bundle) (97ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/test-agent/1.3.13/test-agent-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12;0.8.3!sjson-new-murmurhash_2.12.jar (63ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-cache_2.12;1.3.3!util-cache_2.12.jar (84ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/test-interface/1.0/test-interface-1.0.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compiler-bridge_2.12/1.3.5/compiler-bridge_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;1.3.13!test-agent.jar (57ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0!test-interface.jar (50ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-classfile_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-classfile_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.54/jsch-0.1.54.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-bridge_2.12;1.3.5!compiler-bridge_2.12.jar (60ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/gigahorse-okhttp_2.12/0.5.0/gigahorse-okhttp_2.12-0.5.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-classfile_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-classfile_2.12.jar (63ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#gigahorse-okhttp_2.12;0.5.0!gigahorse-okhttp_2.12.jar (37ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.54!jsch.jar (60ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/gigahorse-core_2.12/0.5.0/gigahorse-core_2.12-0.5.0.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp-urlconnection/3.7.0/okhttp-urlconnection-3.7.0.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/3.14.2/okhttp-3.14.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.eed3si9n#gigahorse-core_2.12;0.5.0!gigahorse-core_2.12.jar (36ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.10!scala-compiler.jar (279ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/ssl-config-core_2.12/0.4.0/ssl-config-core_2.12-0.4.0.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.2/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.squareup.okhttp3#okhttp-urlconnection;3.7.0!okhttp-urlconnection.jar (52ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.squareup.okhttp3#okhttp;3.14.2!okhttp.jar (53ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.12/1.1.2/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe#ssl-config-core_2.12;0.4.0!ssl-config-core_2.12.jar(bundle) (39ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.reactivestreams#reactive-streams;1.0.2!reactive-streams.jar (36ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.3.3/config-1.3.3.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.17.2/okio-1.17.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.26!slf4j-api.jar (39ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-core_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-core_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.12;1.1.2!scala-parser-combinators_2.12.jar(bundle) (49ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.squareup.okio#okio;1.17.2!okio.jar (33ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-persist_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-persist_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/zinc-compile-core_2.12/1.3.5/zinc-compile-core_2.12-1.3.5.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe#config;1.3.3!config.jar(bundle) (57ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/trueaccord/scalapb/scalapb-runtime_2.12/0.6.0/scalapb-runtime_2.12-0.6.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-core_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-core_2.12.jar (71ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-compile-core_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-compile-core_2.12.jar (55ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/trueaccord/lenses/lenses_2.12/0.4.12/lenses_2.12-0.4.12.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/fastparse_2.12/0.4.2/fastparse_2.12-0.4.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#zinc-persist_2.12;1.3.5!zinc-persist_2.12.jar (84ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/fastparse-utils_2.12/0.4.2/fastparse-utils_2.12-0.4.2.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.trueaccord.lenses#lenses_2.12;0.4.12!lenses_2.12.jar (36ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.lihaoyi#fastparse_2.12;0.4.2!fastparse_2.12.jar (40ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lihaoyi/sourcecode_2.12/0.1.3/sourcecode_2.12-0.1.3.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbinary_2.12/0.5.0/sbinary_2.12-0.5.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.trueaccord.scalapb#scalapb-runtime_2.12;0.6.0!scalapb-runtime_2.12.jar (84ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.lihaoyi#fastparse-utils_2.12;0.4.2!fastparse-utils_2.12.jar (39ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/core-macros_2.12/1.3.13/core-macros_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/protocol_2.12/1.3.13/protocol_2.12-1.3.13.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbinary_2.12;0.5.0!sbinary_2.12.jar (35ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.lihaoyi#sourcecode_2.12;0.1.3!sourcecode_2.12.jar (45ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/template-resolver/0.1/template-resolver-0.1.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ipcsocket/ipcsocket/1.0.1/ipcsocket-1.0.1.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#core-macros_2.12;1.3.13!core-macros_2.12.jar (40ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/util-scripted_2.12/1.3.3/util-scripted_2.12-1.3.3.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#protocol_2.12;1.3.13!protocol_2.12.jar (46ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#template-resolver;0.1!template-resolver.jar (37ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/cb372/scalacache-core_2.12/0.20.0/scalacache-core_2.12-0.20.0.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt.ipcsocket#ipcsocket;1.0.1!ipcsocket.jar (42ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.5.6/caffeine-2.5.6.jar ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-839fad1cdc07cf6fc81364d74c323867230432ad/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-839fad1cdc07cf6fc81364d74c323867230432ad.jar ...
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#util-scripted_2.12;1.3.3!util-scripted_2.12.jar (39ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.cb372#scalacache-core_2.12;0.20.0!scalacache-core_2.12.jar (47ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.ben-manes.caffeine#caffeine;2.5.6!caffeine.jar (62ms)
    [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-839fad1cdc07cf6fc81364d74c323867230432ad!ivy.jar (65ms)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    problem while downloading module descriptor: file:/?/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.13/ivys/ivy.xml: Downloaded file size doesn't match expected Content Length for file:/?/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.13/ivys/ivy.xml. Please retry. (3ms)

..... .... ...... 

    problem while downloading module descriptor: file:/?/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.13/sbt-1.3.13.pom: Downloaded file size doesn't match expected Content Length for file:/?/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.3.13/sbt-1.3.13.pom. Please retry. (2ms)



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    6 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved

[info] Updated file /u01/app/jenkins/masters/jenkins-dig-dsh-gsr-jenkins-master-5b9b94f5f7-n6rm4/workspace/kpn.dsh.test.record_feature_test/project/build.properties: set sbt.version to 1.3.13
[info] welcome to sbt 1.3.13 (Alpine Java 11.0.7)

[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has a query component
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

My questions are:

1. Why is sbt downloading a bunch of packages?
2. Will sbt preload prevent sbt from downloading these files? if so how to perform that.
3. what exactly is the problem here, is it "problem with downloading module descriptor" or "URI has a query component" or something else. can someone elaborate on the error.

--Update--
I found out the problem, the problem was the user didn't have access to the sbt directory. So sbt directory didn't get expanded. Which resulted in having a ?. Hence the error URI has a query component..

But would like to know more about behaviour of sbt and sbt preload..

Comment: Can you please describe how you were able to fix the issue?